# What is the cost basis when selling shares received as part of an acquisition?

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax, capital-gain, employee-stock-options, corporate-acquisition

If I vested 100 options in StartupCo at a strike of $1 and I exercise then I will have paid $100 for those shares of StartupCo.

If BigCorp acquires StartupCo and I receive $5 and .25 shares in BigCorp (market value $10 on day of the transaction) per share in StartupCo then I'll receive $500 and 25 shares in BigCorp worth $250.

3 years down the road MegaCorp acquires BigCorp at $2/share and upon surrendering my certificate MegaCorp cuts me a check for $50.

I'm sad that I didn't sell shares in BigCorp at the time of the transaction but more importantly, what is my cost basis for the shares in BigCorp? And are they sold at a loss since BigCorp was at $10 on the day of the acquisition but now they're only worth $2?

Comment: For each acquisition, there's a notice advising how to allocate cost basis from the company being acquired. Is this question theoretical or does it outline a chain of events similar to something you went through?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer This is not theoretical but is the actual process I've gone through. The company names were obviously changed but I also made the numbers simpler. The acquisition of BigCorp by MegaCorp was on the open market. Since posting I've read about Cash to Boot and I realize that gain reported on the BigCorp acquisition is the lesser of Cash received or total gain. With the numbers changed the situation still reflects the actual scenario.

Answer (score 1):

> If I vested 100 options in StartupCo at a strike of $1 and I exercise
>   then I will have paid $100 for those shares of StartupCo.

100 shares / Cost basis $100

> If BigCorp acquires StartupCo and I receive $5 and .25 shares in
>   BigCorp (market value $10 on day of the transaction) per share in
>   StartupCo then I'll receive $500 and 25 shares in BigCorp worth $250.

The notice would spell out the tax consequence of this transaction. But, as I read this, 2/3 of the value at that moment is replaced with cash, 1/3 with stock. $66.67 of your investment returned $500, and tax is due on that difference. (Thank-you, Dave, for comment.)
You now own 25 shares of BigCorp, with a basis of $33.33 (1/3 the original basis)

> 3 years down the road MegaCorp acquires BigCorp at $2/share and upon
>   surrendering my certificate MegaCorp cuts me a check for $50.

The long term gain is $16.67

> I'm sad that I didn't sell shares in BigCorp at the time of the
>   transaction but more importantly, what is my cost basis for the shares
>   in BigCorp? And are they sold at a loss since BigCorp was at $10 on
>   the day of the acquisition but now they're only worth $2?

See the math above. And a warning. All takeovers come with a notice of how to allocate basis. It's easy if there's a takeover of 100% cash, it's just a sale. The cash/stock mix is rarely as clean as my answer suggests. That notice would tell you the exact percents. The funny thing about the market? I can always wish I bought lower, sold higher. If I bought at the very low, and sold at very high, I'd just wish I bought more. It's possible to invest and grow rich over time, but never be happy with the short term results.

Comment: At startup-to-bigcorp you also had a realized/taxable gain of $500-$66.67. Also, if you missed the notice at the time, IME they remain available from the successor company's website for many many years. Don't ask why I know this :}

Comment: Yes Dave. I should have added that line into my answer. Will do it when I’m not driving. 